# What does `const&` mean in `const char* const& _str`?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, parameterized-constructor

This is a constructor of class `MyString`:

```
MyString(const char* const& _str = nullptr);
```

Inside it, we give `const char *` and then again `const&` and then `_str`, what does `const&` mean here?

Comment: This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `_str` is a *reference to a const pointer to a const char*

Comment: You read types outwards from the variable name. In this case, since there's nothing to the right of `str_`, you read right-to-left: `&` reference to `const` `*` pointer to `const char`.

Comment: Sites like cdecl may be helpful to interpret complex declarations, but I would argue it is not really needed in this case, also it fails to work for rvalue references. Anyway I'm providing a [link](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+char*+const%26+_str).